# SFML Can't draw the object even after overide the virtual draw function

Tags: c++, sfml

I have created a card class that implements Drawable class, and I have also override the function draw, but after I have created the card object and tried to draw it using window.draw, it gave me an error saying that the card object I created is not a type of drawable. When I tried to cast card object to a drawable using (sf::Drawable)card, it says the draw function is not implemented. I am very confused.

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Card: public sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable
{
public:

    Card();
    Card(int v, char c);

    void setPos(sf::Vector2f v);
    sf::Vector2f getPos();

private:

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &window, sf::RenderStates state) const;
    void creatCard();

    sf::RectangleShape cardBackground;
    sf::Text faceValue;
    sf::Sprite suit;
    int _value;
    char _suit;
    sf::Vector2f pos;

};

Card::Card()
{
    _value = 1;
    _suit = 'H';

    creatCard();
}

void Card::draw(sf::RenderTarget &window, sf::RenderStates state) const
{

    window.draw(cardBackground);
    window.draw(faceValue);

}

void Card::creatCard()
{
    sf::Image img;
    sf::Texture texture;

    switch (toupper(_suit)) {
        case 'S':
            if(!img.loadFromFile("card_suits.png"))
                cout << "Fail to load card_suits.png" << endl;
            break;
        case 'H':
            if(!img.loadFromFile("card_suits2.png"))
                cout << "Fail to load card_suits.png" << endl;
            break;
        case 'D':
            if(!img.loadFromFile("card_suits3.png"))
                cout << "Fail to load card_suits.png" << endl;
            break;
        case 'C':
            if(!img.loadFromFile("card_suits4.png"))
                cout << "Fail to load card_suits.png" << endl;
    }

    texture.loadFromImage(img);
    suit.setTexture(texture);

    cardBackground.setSize(sf::Vector2f(300, 600));
    cardBackground.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
}
```

```
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500, 32), "Test");
    Card card();

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.draw(card);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Card card();` is a function declaration. See [tag:most-vexing-parse]. You'll want to declare that either as `Card card;` or `Card card{};` (with curly brackets).

Answer (score 1):

The card is draw, but you just don't see it.
Sprite in SFML use reference to Texture:

> When you set the texture of a sprite, all it does internally is store a pointer to the texture instance. Therefore, if the texture is destroyed or moves elsewhere in memory, the sprite ends up with an invalid texture pointer.

To fix this, you need to store the Texture.

cf: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem